# Automatically Creates tables from another database's table

Tags: sql-server

when i create a new database it automatically creates tables which is already at another database and i need no table when i create a new database so to stop this i need your help..

Comment: What table is automatically created?

Comment: ut you don't speak about the system tables, do you?

Answer (score 5):

If someone has created tables in the system model database, then these tables will be created in any new databases.

Comment: Nice information.. happy to know that